# How in jest test DPI

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I have function that change size of image depending on `window.devicePixelRatio`

and now i want to proper test it.

```
const wrapper = mount(myComponent, {
    propsData: {
      size: {
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
      },
      format: 'jpeg',
      filename: 'path/to/image.jpg',
      dpi: 1,
    },
  })

it('check if higer dpi generate double sized images', () => {
 wrapper.setProps({ size: { height: 600, width: 400 }, format: 'jpeg', filename: 'www.path/to/image.jpg', quality: 80, dpi: 2 })
  expect(imgWrapper.attributes('height')).toBe('600')
  expect(imgWrapper.attributes('width')).toBe('400')
  expect(imgWrapper.attributes('src')).toBe('www.yoursUrl.com/w=800,h=1200,f=jpeg,q=80/www.path/to/image.jpg')
})
```

and that what test show

```
Expected: "www.yoursUrl.com/w=800,h=1200,f=jpeg,q=80/www.path/to/image.jpg"
Received: "www.yoursUrl.com/w=400,h=600,f=jpeg,q=80/www.path/to/image.jpg"
```

thx for ideas

Code in compoonent

Props

```
props: {
 dpi: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1,
 },
}
```

Methods

```
isHigherDPI() {
  return window.devicePixelRatio > this.dpi
}

imageRouteFinalImage() {
      if (this.isHigherDPI()) {
        width = this.size.width * 2
        height = this.size.height * 2
      }

      return `${www.yoursUrl.com/w=${width},h=${height},/www.path/to/image.jpg`
},
```

Comment: What's your question? what do you expect as output and what do you get?

Comment: how do you mock `window.devicePixelRatio` in your tests?

Comment: @skyboyer i update code :)

Comment: good, I actually was talking about how do you _mock_ it, not _use_ it. See, jest/jsdom by default suppose `devicePixelRation` to be 0, so you have to explicitly provide some mocked value

Comment: @skyboyer on top i set in props `dpi` for 1 and in test down bellow set `dpi: 2 `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.devicePixelRatio` is already writable, so you could simply set it before you run your test:

```js
describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  it('check if higher dpi...', () => {
    window.devicePixelRatio = 3
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, { propsData: {/*...*/} })
    expect(wrapper.vm.imgSrc).toEqual('foo.jpg?dpi=high')
  })
})
```

On the other hand, if you need to verify `window.devicePixelRatio` was read, you could [spy on](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) the `window` object, and [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) the target property:

```js
describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  it('check if higher dpi...', () => {
    const devicePixelRatioGetter = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(3)

    jest.spyOn(global, 'window', 'get').mockImplementation(() => Object.defineProperty({}, 'devicePixelRatio', {
      get: devicePixelRatioGetter
    }))

    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, { propsData: {/*...*/} })
    expect(wrapper.vm.imgSrc).toEqual('foo.jpg?dpi=high')
    expect(devicePixelRatioGetter).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: I believe changes to `window` will persist into subsequent tests. It is safer to always use the mocked approach, to preserve test isolation